# How do I print logic field on page--node.html.twig?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

This code printing 0 or 1

```
{{ node.field_some_logic.value }}
```

I want he print NO or YES.

Somobody know, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simple logic, you could try using

```
{{ node.field_some_logic.value ? 'YES' : 'NO' }}
```

See **ternary operator** on https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html